# Uninstalling the application silently / automatially

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible that my application, when exit, uninstalls itself automatically, without any user intervention and involvement?

Thanks

Comment: How is it installed? MSI, file copy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need to detect the shutdown (perhaps via the [`Application.OnExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onexit.aspx) event), and then in the event handler you could call [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) that will kick off the uninstall.

You will need to make sure your application has fully existed by the time the uninstaller needs to remove it.

Comment: That last sentence is the rub.

Comment: @Hans Passant - absolutely. I would probably run it as a separate app that will poll the processes on the system and only kick off the actual uninstall after seeing that the process in question is no more.

Comment: Hi Oded, could you kindly give me the code..............Does it work silently or it needs user intervention.  I need silent uninstall

Comment: @user415037 - There is no code. This is simply a suggestion on how such a thing _may_ work and what classes to look at.